# Mocking an object initialised inside a method under test

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to test a class which instatiates another class within it. It is the instatinated class call I want to mock.

Is this possible or is they a way around it/ simpler way I am missing?

Below I have written up a simpler example which still has the same problemts as my main code.

```
public interface my_interface
{
    int returns_25();
}

public class class_i_want_to_mock : my_interface
{
    public int returns_25()
    {
        // TEST SHOULD FAIL SO NEED MOCK TO PASS THE CASE
        return 7645745;
    }
}
```

In another namespace (it has access):

```
public class class_to_test
{
        public static int returns_25()
        {
            class_i_want_to_mock _tempClass= new class_i_want_to_mock ();

            // Will return 7645745 unless moq changes return value
            int _temp_int = _tempClass.returns_25()
            return _temp_int;
        }
}
```

My test (which fails):

```
    [Test]
    public void test_returns_25()
    {
        // Mock 
        Mock<my_interface> myMock = new Mock<my_interface>();
        myMock.Setup(m => m.returns_25()).Returns(25);

        // Act
        int return_number = class_to_test.returns_25();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(25, return_number);
    }
```

Comment: Can you restructure the code?

Comment: Yes. However, the methods in "my_interface" are called throughout the entire code so would like to keep seperate. But if it helps in testing could restructure.

Comment: This is the a good reason to be injecting the dependencies instaed of making methods responsible for their construction. If you can inject `my_interface` into `class_to_test` then you can mock. If you new up a concrete implementation then your not mocking anything.

Comment: Thanks! Injection seems to work. I will post the updated code/solution up here in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code thanks to the injection idea from JSteward above.

Code is in same order

```
public interface my_interface
{
    int returns_25();
}

public class class_i_want_to_mock : my_interface
{
    public int returns_25()
    {
        // TEST SHOULD FAIL SO NEED MOCK TO PASS THE CASE
        return 7645745;
    }
}
```

Next class, notice the injection of the interface

```
public class class_to_test
{
        public static int returns_25(my_interface _temp_interface)
        {

            // Will return 7645745 unless moq changes return value
            int _temp_int = _temp_interface.returns_25()
            return _temp_int;
        }
}
```

And the test. Note the object of the Mock class has to be used (myMock.Object)

```
[Test]
public void test_returns_25()
{
    // Mock 
    Mock<my_interface> myMock = new Mock<my_interface>();
    myMock.Setup(m => m.returns_25()).Returns(25);

    // Act
    int return_number = class_to_test.returns_25(myMock.Object);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(25, return_number);
}
```